# I cant see my images in my flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

I did to make a simple pokedex application for trying myself. I completed my project and I did not get any issue in android studio.Other hand, When I started my application, I cant see images to get in my project in emulator. Can anyone help me for this issue .

Can look at this extension.
https://github.com/AlejandroTaichu/Pokedex.git

I want to see images in my project when I was opened my project.I am new on programming so I cant fix that.

Comment: Welcome! ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541)! Can you please ask an actual question? You can see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: Welcome! As long as you follow the guidance in ["What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/11107541), then [you don't need to tell us that you are new to `X`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296391/11107541).

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten extension of image in your code

```
child: Image.asset("images/${pokemon.name}")),
```

Change to below code

```
child: Image.asset("images/${pokemon.name}.png")),
```

Or add image extension(.png) in names of pokeList

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the image name(path) according to the assets image path include the image type.

[image]

Next you need to create a future and call `future` on Future Builder widget.

```dart
  late final future = callPokemon();
```

```dart
class _PokemonHomepageState extends State<PokemonHomepage> {
  Future<List<Pokemons>> callPokemon() async {
    var pokeList = <Pokemons>[];

    var p1 = Pokemons(pokeId: 1, name: "Charmender.png", health: 100, power: 250);
    var p2 = Pokemons(pokeId: 2, name: "squirtle.png", health: 150, power: 300);
    var p3 = Pokemons(pokeId: 3, name: "balbazar.png", health: 300, power: 500);

    pokeList.add(p1);
    pokeList.add(p2);
    pokeList.add(p3);

    return pokeList;
  }

  late final future = callPokemon();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:
          AppBar(title: const Text("POKEDEX"), backgroundColor: Colors.green),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Pokemons>>(
        future: future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

Made a [pr on git](https://github.com/AlejandroTaichu/Pokedex/pull/1), you can merge it

Comment: I maged it your changes but still I cant see images on emulator. I dont know why ..

Comment: Try to pull on local and then  `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: Yes I did that but I still couldnt see my images .. I am new in flutter maybe I miss something what you say. My english not so good sory for that

Comment: try to run on another device, like chrome `flutter run -d c`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `flutter_gen` (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gen) for assets. I recently found this package & its really helpful when using multiple images from assets.

With flutter_gen you can just setup few things one time & you can directly get image widgets from this package.

1. Setup flutter_gen

```
 dart pub global activate flutter_gen
```

2. Add these runners in your dev dependencies

```
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner:
  flutter_gen_runner:
```

3. Setup path of generated assets file

```
flutter_gen:
  output: lib/generated/
```

There are many options in this step. You can check their documentation.

4. Set image folder path

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
```

5. Put your images in the path added
6. After doing these steps you just need to run

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

This file will generate an assets file name `assets.gen.dart` inside the `lib/generated` folder as we setup in step 3.
Note that you have to run this command whenever you change folder name or images to regerenated the `assets.gen.dart`

Thats it.

When you are done with these steps, you can directly get the images from this `assets.gen.dart` file like this

```
import 'package:flutter_boilerplate/generated/assets.gen.dart';

Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 200, child: Assets.images.cat1.image(width: 200),
  ),
),
```

The plus benefit is that these assets provided widget support intellisense, so there is no chance for spelling mistake. Plus you directly get a widget from this with all the properties of default Image widget.
It also supports advance image types like svg, lottie, flare as well.

Comment: thank for this explanation. I am tryinng this

Comment: @AlihanTayçu
Is this working after flutter_gen?